# Windows API Trace from User-Mode to Kernel-Mode

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, kernel32, apimonitor

I would like to trace/log the entire flow of an API call from user-mode to kernel mode.
For Example if a user-mode application calls the FindFirstFile() API, I would like to log the following:

FindFirstFile -> NtQueryDirectoryFile -> SYSCALL -> KiSystemService -> KiFastCallEntry -> NtQueryDirectoryFile -> IRP -> ...

Is there any program today that can do that? (Rohitab API Monitor can do User-Mode API tracing but not both).
If not, what is the most elegant way to develop such a capability?

Answer (score 1):

Since ProcExplorer is giving full Thread trace, one can do it, too.
I found this website that explains how to implement a kernel-mode GetThreadContext() in order to complete the stack picture (with StackWalk64).

http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2009/02/grabbing-kernel-thread-contexts-the-process-explorer-way/#note1

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this, by using windbg
this is program from microsoft, that can debug the user mode and also the kernel mode.

you can start from here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg

and also if you want read about this and see some example of doing this you can see here also.

http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=257

Good luck :-)